# I'm having appendChild() issues and problems centering my div's inside one larger div all at once?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, divide

I would like to add text to the center of each one of these tic tac toe blocks that says something along the lines of **Pick Me!** using the `document.createTextNode()` and then `.appendChild()` methods.

```
var text = document.createTextNode("Choose Me!");
var div = document.getElementById('block');
div.appendChild(text);
```

Also I created the tic tac toe layout but have been unable get them all centered as a group of div's inside one larger div. After trying a few of the methods I found on here I still had no luck.

```
  .block{
     display:inline-block;
     background-color: azure;
     border:2px solid black;
     font-family: fantasy;
     height:150px;
     width:200px;
     padding-top:5px;
     justify-content: center;
     position: relative; 

   }  

  body{
     background-color: beige; 
   }

 .game {
     height:500px;
     width:700px;
     background-color: gainsboro;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto; 
  }
```

And here is a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/g3fg9or1/2/) for a more clear picture of what's going on

Comment: `block` is a class not an id!!!

Comment: So - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nq8qnm7m/1/

Comment: Haha I'm an idiot sorry! Any idea about the centering divs inside the larger div?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nq8qnm7m/2/